# Cannot find module '../lib/completion' Inspite of installing Completion

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sass, completion

I am getting this error Cannot find module '../lib/completion' however I have installed completion and completion.js is present in the lib file.

```
->gulp compile
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/completion'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\wamp23\www\mfe\ref\gulpfile.js:13:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I was unable to determine the cause of the issue. However, an uninstall then reinstall of `gulp` solved it.

Uninstall:

```
npm uninstall gulp --save
```

Re-install:

```
npm install gulp --save
```

Comment: this keeps hapening each time after I run the gulp task, I uninstall then install and again I get the error

Comment: What kind of file system events might cause this? Said differently, I too am experiencing this problem. But since my code is in a DropBox folder that is constantly being synced, I wonder if Dropbox is causing the problem.

Comment: While this solution works, I wanted to add what I'm doing that is causing me to have to uninstall and reinstall `gulp`: I press `Control + C` to end running gulp tasks. Then the next gulp task I try to execute gives the error message `Error: Cannot find module '../lib/completion'`.

Comment: @TzookBarNoy I too am having the same issue. Did you resolve it by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

I removed the entire node_modules/ folder, and did a reinstall, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js YOURTASKNAME

or

uninstall the local gulp and install again, which will solve the problem.

Comment: usual problem when installing gulp locally in some other pc or location and copy/move the project(node_modules) to new location, causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

problem in gulp module so, uninstall and install the module.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue uninstalling and reinstalling the gulp module didn't help for me I then removed the node_modules folder and did npn install it seems to be working now.